# Why is my ORDER BY clause being duplicated with this ActiveRecord scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, sql-order-by, default-scope

I have this model:

```
class Coupon < ActiveRecord::Base

  default_scope order(:created_at)
  scope :inactive, where(:active => false)

end
```

I'm seeing some weird duplication of the `ORDER BY` clause when using the `inactive` scope:

```
> Coupon.scoped.to_sql
 => "SELECT `coupons`.* FROM `coupons` ORDER BY `coupons`.`created_at`" 
> Coupon.inactive.to_sql
 => "SELECT `coupons`.* FROM `coupons` WHERE (`coupons`.`active` = 0) ORDER BY `coupons`.`created_at`, `coupons`.`created_at`"
```

This one really has me scratching my head. I'm using the [MetaWhere](http://metautonomo.us/projects/metawhere/) gem if that's relevant.

**Update**: I've isolated this to a [MetaWhere](http://metautonomo.us/projects/metawhere/) bug. Doesn't happen with vanilla ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bundler was pulling down `meta_where 0.9.9.2`. Upgrading to `~> 1.0` fixes the issue.